# Regular syslogd clusvcmgrd messages dumped to ALL terminals

Tags: redhat, cluster, terminal, syslog

Just a few days ago we are suddenly now getting messages like this dumped to every open terminal every couple minutes:

```
Message from syslogd@hartnell at Wed Sep  2 11:15:27 2009 ...
hartnell clusvcmgrd[5887]:  readServiceBlock: Service number mismatch 2, 0.
```

We are running:

> Linux hartnell.cluster 2.4.21-32.0.1.ELsmp #1 SMP Tue May 17 17:46:36 EDT 2005 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 3 (Taroon Update 9)

Any ideas why this might suddenly start? Maybe a log file has filled up??

Answer (score 1):

From `man syslog.conf`:

```
          # Emergency messages will be displayed using wall
          #
          *.=emerg                     *

   This rule tells the syslogd to write all emergency messages to all cur‐
   rently logged in users.  This is the wall action.
```

You may have other such settings in `/etc/syslog.conf` that are causing this message to be written to all terminals. You can either change the way your logging is configured or fix the problem that is causing the message.

This should be an anomalous condition. You might be having hardware problems with the drive.

See [this discussion](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=120934) and [this advisory](http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2005-047.html) for more information.